# How to save Angular global variable in my application

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-components

I am new to Angular 2 + applications. I want to use some global objects in my Angular 5 application. I have some angular components like this:

- MapConponenet
- LayersComponent
- ZoomComponent

My `MapConponenet` will be created, when application start and it will create a global `map` object. And my other components will use that `map` object.

`LayerComponent` and `ZoomComponent` needs `map` object and does not work without map object. So I could not decade where can I store this global map object using angular 2+ applications.

- Should I use a global variable?
- Should I create a service?
- Should I use a browser localstorege?

Comment: It sounds like you should create a map.service to handle all the map related actions. There you can also handle the persistency of the map object

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service file and declare the object in file .
by the injecting the service file you can easily access the object all over the project.